# Agregar un espacio en blanco o separador

Tags: html, bootstrap

¿Cómo puedo agregar un espacio o separador entre el input contraseña y el botón registrarse? Recién estoy arrancando con todo esto de las paginas web, gracias de antemano.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.4.1/litera/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Registrarse
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form (submit)="signUp()">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class="from-group">
                        <input type="text" name="contraseña" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" >
                        Registrarse
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.4.1/litera/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Registrarse
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form (submit)="signUp()">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class="from-group">
                        <input type="text" name="contraseña" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3" >
                        Registrarse
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Puedes usar el auxiliar de margin de bootstrap:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3">
                            Registrarse
</button>
```

La m es de margin, la t es de top ( t = top, b = bottom, l = left , r= right) y despues del guión los pixeles de espacio que quieres agregar.

Comment: No me funciono ;(

Comment: Revisa de nuevo, lo agregué a tu código de ejemplo y funciona.

Comment: Ahora si, muchas gracias estaba poniendo el mt-3 afuera de las "

Answer (score 0):

Desde una regla CSS simple

- Muy simple has uso de un selector de atributo, para identificar aquel `input` cuyo `name` es `contraseña`
- Posterior harás uso de la propiedad `margin-top` para indicar los pixeles de separación con respecto del elemento que lo antecede

Finalmente quedaría así:

```
  input[name="contraseña"] {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: No me funciono,me olvide mencionar que estaba utilizando boostrap (no se si es relevante) , ya edite mi publicación

Comment: Para que te funcione, debes declarar esta regla css después del llamado de tu línea de bootstrap, debería funcionarte @Franco

Answer (score 0):

Usa la etiqueta `<br>` entre ambos elementos, lo cual te dará un salto de línea.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
</div>
<br>
<div class="from-group">
    <input type="text" name="contraseña" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
</div>
```